# Where does the function end to add success message/send email - Django/Python

Tags: python, django, email, django-models, django-views

In this view, I would like to add a success message for completing the deletion, as well as email the owner with a notification of the deletion.

I am using this code from someone else, so I am not too familiar with it.

Where would I insert the success message and the "send_mail" function in this code? Again, I would like to insert it where the function is successful, but just before the redirect occurs.

Thank you!

```
class DeleteEventView(DeleteView):
    template_name = 'schedule/delete_event.html'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'event_id'
    model = Event

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(DeleteEventView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['next'] = self.get_success_url()
        return ctx

    def get_success_url(self):
        """
        After the event is deleted there are three options for redirect, tried in
        this order:

        # Try to find a 'next' GET variable
        # If the key word argument redirect is set
        # Lastly redirect to the event detail of the recently create event
        """
        next = self.kwargs.get('next') or reverse('day_calendar', args=[self.object.calendar.slug])
        next = get_next_url(self.request, next)
        return next

    ## Override dispatch to apply the permission decorator
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    @method_decorator(check_event_permissions)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(DeleteEventView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the `delete()` method:

```
from django.contrib import messages

class DeleteEventView(DeleteView):
    ...
    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(DeleteEventView, self).delete(request,
                                                       *args, **kwargs)
        deleted_event = self.object
        messages.success(request, 'Event %s deleted.' % deleted_event)
        return response
```